# Why does a voltage appears between $A$ and $C$ when this coil is rotated?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

> [image]
>
> Find the voltage between the points $A$ and $C$ when a wire is conecting $A$ and $D$.

We know that there is a magnetic field $B$ perpendicular and entering in the papers plane, the semicircular metal has an electrical resistence $\lambda$ by unit of lenght and it is spinning around $C$ with constang angular speed $\omega$. The wire connecting $A$ and $D$ has electrical resistence zero.

What I can't understand in this situation is that, when connecting $A$ and $D$, we get a coil in a closed shape. In order to have some voltage we need some magnetic flux variation, but the coil is only spinning in a plane perpendicular to $B$. So, for me, there is no flux variation and the voltage between $A$ and $C$ is zero. Thinking about this, I also wanted to know if there would be voltage if instead of spinning, the metal were only moving with constant or variable speed in the same plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\rA{{\rm A}} \def\rC{{\rm C}} \def\rD{{\rm D}} \def\rP{{\rm P}}$
I find it difficult to write an answer without knowing the level I am
supposed to hold. Furthermore, the phrasing of the problem looks
rather strange to me. I don't understand why resistance is given and
which purpose the electrical connection between A and D should serve.

Also the use of "voltage" is liable to misunderstandings. In physical
parlance the right term is "potential difference" (pd), but referring
to a closed circuit "electromotive force" (emf) should be used.

You are right that in the closed circuit ACD no emf is induced and no
current can flow. (This is why I can't see the reason to give the
wire's resistance.) But this does not mean that no pd exists between
different points, whether the circuit is closed or open. Let's see
why.

Consider for instance arc AC of the wire. It is electrically neutral,
holding positive charges bound in the metal lattice and free
electrons. If the wire stands still all these charges stand still too
(for electrons, in the average). When AC rotates around C, every point
P of the wire acquires a speed, higher for points farther from C
and directed perpendicularly to the radius CP.

Now Lorentz' force comes into play: it is perpendicular both to P's velocity and to the field $\vec B$. For a positive charge its direction is towards C, for a negative one, it's opposite. The force's intensity is $qvB$ ($q$ the charge). As to positive charges, Lorentz' force exists but has no effect since these charges are bound. But electrons are free, and are driven towards the extremity A. They would tend to pile up there, leaving free of electrons the other extreme C. But electrons repel each other, so you can see that an equilibrium is reached, with
abundance of electrons near A, scarcity near C.

A more formal description of the process is the following. When
equilibrium is achieved electrons stand still again, which means that
the net force acting on each single electron is zero. This force is
the resultant of the Lorentz force previously described and that of
the electric field generated by all other electrons accumulated near A
and removed from C. Considering that electrons are negative, the
direction of this field is from C towards A, and stronger near A,
as Lorentz force is.

If in a wire an electric field is present, you can speak as well of a
pd between extremes C and A, the potential being higher in C, lower
in A. It would remain to compute the value of this pd. I give only the
result, as I don't know if you could follow the derivation:
$$V(\rC) - V(\rA) = \frac12\,\omega\,B\,l_1^2$$
where $l_1$ is the length of chord CA.

A final look at the other tracts of the wire, with special regard to
the closed circuit. Exactly the same will happen in tract CD:
$$V(\rC) - V(\rD) = \frac12\,\omega\,B\,l_2^2$$
where $l_2$ is the length of chord AD. The same kind of computations
could be done also for segment AD if the circuit is closed, obtaining
$$V(\rD) - V(\rA) = \frac12\,\omega\,B\,(l_1^2 - l_2^2).$$

If you compute the emf as the sum of all these pd's, taken with the
right signs:
$${\rm emf} = [V(\rA) - V(\rC)] + [V(\rD) - V(\rA)] + 
[V(\rC) - V(\rD)] = 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

-Because your wires are spinning relative to the B field, it is as if there was a current in them (the wires have electrons, and the wires are moving, therefore the electrons are moving)

-The B field will therefore generate an EMF